# Lag in recursive CTE

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursion, common-table-expression

I have a recursive CTE and am attempting to use a lag in it.  However, the lag is returning only the default value (in this case 0).  I need this lag to compute a running product of the last 7 numbers, which will then be used in another recursive computation.  Here is my code:

```
WITH f2(n,q,qlag) as(
    SELECT 0,1E0,1E0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT f2.n+1
        ,f1.q
        ,LAG(f1.q,7,0) OVER(Order by f1.n)
    FROM    
        f2
        join f1
        on f1.n=f2.n
)
SELECT *
FROM f2
```

Is there a way to use values from a previous row (7 back in this case) in a recursive CTE?

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of the logic you want to implement.  I've written more than a handful of recursive CTEs and never needed to use `lag()`.

Comment: Normally `LAG` would be implemented in the outer query, not the inner. I doubt there will be 7 rows "back" in the lower query portal, as it likely only contains 1 row (due to the `ON f1.n=f2.n` clause)

Comment: @GordonLinoff I'm not sure how to concisely provide sample data or explain the logic.  In short, I have a table of qs and I need to perform a recursive function on the table which utilizes q values from two different rows (with constant offset).

Comment: @Larnu I think you're right about what is causing the problem.  The issue I'm having with doing it in the outer query is that I need to use the lagged value in a recursive calculation.

Comment: That doesn't really make sense, @KalevMaricq . You only have scope of the rows generated by the iteration of the statement, when using `LAG`, not all of them (past, present, and future). If it's not working in the outer query, it's because you're implementing it wrong. With no sample data or expected result though, it's impossible for us to tell you want the correct implmentation is.

Comment: @KalevMaricq . . . You should ask a *new* question, with sample data, desired results, and an explanation of the logic you want to implement.